# Cannot view .html()

Tags: jquery, html

Currently I am working on Tic Tac Toe and  I am experience some difficulty with the win conditions.

I am using a .*one(click*, to ensure that no div can be clicked more than once.

The *xoClick* counts the times this has happened and toggles the switch of *player* between **X** and **O**

The win condition is the second if statement in the `*$('.block').one('click',function(){*`

I am using console.logs everywhere to view what the code can see in attempt to view where it breaks.

Currently, I am trying to view `.r1c1` in the first if statement and it can't. This is my title.

The console.logs before the conditional can see the *.html()* of the .block but the conditional itself produces nothing in console.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>TicTacToe</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="r1">
                <div class="r1c1 block"></div>
                <div class="r1c2 block"></div>
                <div class="r1c3 block"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="r2">
                <div class="r2c1 block"></div>
                <div class="r2c2 block"></div>
                <div class="r2c3 block"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="r3">
                <div class="r3c1 block"></div>
                <div class="r3c2 block"></div>
                <div class="r3c3 block"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <aside>
            <input type="submit" value="Reset" id="resetButton">
            <p>Player 1 Score</p>
            <p class="p1Score"></p>
            <p>Player 2 Score</p>
            <p class="p2Score"></p>
            <p>Cat Game</p>
            <p class="catGame"></p>
        </aside>
        <div>
            <h1>Project Notes:</h1>
            <p>This project was done entirely by me. There was no cheating by coping code. There were lots of Google Queries but none consisting of how to make Tic Tac Toe. Just looked up elements that I need in order to complete this personal project.</p>
        </div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
```

This is my CSS

```
body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.container{
    width: 80%;
    height: 450px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

/* For Spacing  */

.r1,.r2,.r3{
    width: 100%; 
    height: 33%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin: -1px auto;
}


.r1c1,.r1c2,.r1c3,.r2c1,.r2c2,.r2c3,.r3c1,.r3c2,.r3c3{
    width: 33%; 
    height: 98%; 
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* For Borders on the blocks */
/* Left Line for the top column */

.r1c1,.r1c2,.r2c1,.r2c2,.r3c1,.r3c2{
    border-right: black 2px solid;
}

/* Bottom Lines for blocks needed. */
.r1c1,.r1c2,.r1c3,.r2c1,.r2c2,.r2c3{
        border-bottom: black 2px solid;
}

/* Styling for aside */

aside{
    padding: 5% 1% 1% 1%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}
/* for styling the X and O*/ 
.block{
    font-size: 900%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

And here is the JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Variable that will be needed
    var p1Score = 0;
    var p2Score = 0;
    var catGame = 0; 
    var xoClick = 0; 
    var player 
    // For the divs to be clicked one and track the clicks 

    $('.block').one('click',function(){
        //for alternation

        xoClick++
        //console.log(xoClick);
        //the alternating 
        if((xoClick % 2 === 0)===false){
            player = "X";
            $(this).html(player);
        } else if((xoClick % 2 === 0)===true){
            player = "O";
            $(this).html(player);
        } else {
            null
        }

        //For Troubleshooting and monitoring 
              // console.log($('.r1c1').html());
             // console.log($('.r1c2').html());
             // console.log($('.r1c3').html());
             // console.log($('.r2c1').html());
             // console.log($('.r2c2').html());
             // console.log($('.r2c3').html());
             // console.log($('.r3c1').html());
             // console.log($('.r3c2').html());
             // console.log($('.r3c3').html());

        //Win condition
        if ($('.r1c1').html() === $('.r1c2').html() === $('.r1c3').html()){
             console.log(player + ' Wins!');
              console.log($('.r1c1').html());
             // console.log($('.r1c2').html());
             // console.log($('.r1c3').html());
        } else if ($('.r2c1').html() === $('.r2c2').html() === $('.r2c3').html()){
            console.log(player + ' Wins!'); 
        } else if ($('.r3c1').html() === $('.r3c2').html() === $('.r3c3').html()){
            console.log(player + ' Wins!'); 
        } else if ($('.r1c1').html() === $('.r2c1').html() === $('.r3c1').html()){
            console.log(player + ' Wins!'); 
        } else if ($('.r1c2').html() === $('.r3c2').html() === $('.r3c2').html()){
            console.log(player + ' Wins!'); 
        } else if ($('.r3c3').html() === $('.r3c3').html() === $('.r3c3').html()){
            console.log(player + ' Wins!'); 
        } else if ($('.r1c1').html() === $('.r2c2').html() === $('.r3c3').html()){
            console.log(player + ' Wins!'); 
        } else if ($('.r1c3').html() === $('.r3c2').html() === $('.r3c1').html()){
            console.log(player + ' Wins!'); 
         } else { null };
         //proving that no matter where I put it; it can see .r1c1
         //console.log($('.r1c1').html());

    });
    // This is for the reset button 


});
```

Please let me know if there is anything else you need.

The rest and counters will come later.

Comment: Have you tried doing $('.block').on('click',function() instead of $('.block').one('click',function()?

Comment: Doesn't $('.r1c1').html() === $('.r1c2').html() === $('.r1c3').html() evaluate true when no one has clicked on any of the boxes on the top row?

Comment: @LazyCoder I know .on(click would work but I am trying to make it so that they users can only click on each block only once which is why I am using .one(click

Comment: @Bindrid I think that may be true. But that is why I have it running only when the .one() is triggered and after the injection of the "X" or "O".

Answer (score 1):

For the win conditions, you cannot check the equality of three items with your current condition syntaxes. You can use a partial [transitive relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation) and check if none of the items are blank.

So instead of using

```
$('.r1c1').html() === $('.r1c2').html() === $('.r1c3').html()
```

use

```
$('.r1c1').html() === $('.r1c2').html() && 
$('.r1c2').html() === $('.r1c3').html() && 
$('.r1c1').html() !== "" && 
$('.r1c2').html() !== "" && 
$('.r1c3').html() !== ""
```

It is like saying that if *x* = *y*, *y* = *z*, and neither *x*, *y*, nor *z* is blank, then execute the statements.

The reason for the blank test is that you do not want the script to announce a win if the equivalent values are blanks.

Comment: Thank you very much Jon.  I'll try that. When I attempt to console.log() .r1c1 or .r1c2 or .r1c3 in the second conditional the console reports nothing. Perhaps this is what is causing this to be a problem.